# How do I return data from a GCMListenerService to an Activity using a ResultReceiver?

Tags: java, android, servlets, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a GCMListenerService that will be used for push notifications from my server to my client. I need this listener to interrupt a thread that is running in the Presenter (my project is structured using the MVP pattern). However, I do not know how to pass a result receiver to the Service because I don't think I can overrride onStartCommand(). The other option would be a LocalBroadCast Manager, but I'd like the message to go through even when the activity is paused, so I don't think a local broadcast manager would work.

Answer (score 0):

create abstract BroadcastReceiver as follows :

```
public abstract  class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        onDataRefresh(intent);
    }
    protected abstract void onDataRefresh(Intent intent);
}
```

and use it in the activity as follow:

```
class Acb extends Activity{
onCreate(){
DataReceiver data = new DataReceiver(
    @Override
    protected void onMenuItemUpdate(Intent intent) {

});
}
}
```

whatever the data you passed using `sendBroadcast(intent);` ,that data you can access here .